# How to reuse one custom listview activity in another activity?

Tags: android, android-listview

Can I use my existing ListView as a sub-view in another view.

eg. I have a custom view, players list, I have implemented with a ListActivity and ArrayAdapter and is working fine.

Now I want a way to get this listview as View object so that I can add this view object as a child to another view.

I am thinking like, to build entire listview: my ListActivity is calling the ArrayAdapter iteratively by passing ArrayList item each time to build a list item view.

If I am correct, I need a way to call the same ArrayAdapter and need to prepare a ListView Object, right?

Can anybody plz help me.

Thanks in advance.
vpapana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ListView and the Adapter are two different things:

- The data is somewhere (in an array or if you need to be able to add/remove items, in an ArrayList)
- The Adapter contains the data
- The ListView displays it.

So:

1. Construct your empty ArrayList
2. Construct your adapter based on your ArrayList
3. Construct your ListView based on the Adapter

Then:

1. Each time you need to change the data, update the ArrayList
2. Call Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
3. Watch your list being automatically updated :)

To add your list to a tablelayout, see the [API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html), [SDK tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html) and [this tutorial](http://huuah.com/using-tablelayout-on-android/) which has a specific section on how to add rows programmatically.

Comment: Thank you for your answser. I am doing exactly in the same way as you mentioned for my players list view. But my question is how to use this existing list view as a child of another view?

Comment: The other widget must be able to have children (for instance any of the Layouts or a TabView, a ViewSwitcher, ...). How you set your list view as a child depends on the parent view.

Comment: Yes, I want to add the existing list view as a table row of another layout. How can i do that?

Comment: Hi Marvin... after a long time... 
i want to explain my requirement more detail, as i said, i have player list (custom list view, populated with the array adapter) activity-1 to display long list of players, now i need to display top 2 players in another activity-2 (today it is top 2, it may vary to top-5)... so i want to reuse my player list components for activity-2.

And one more concern, can i user more than one list view for an activity (because my activity-2 already has a listview).

Thank you.